in Maui when making a composite control how to handle using a trigger or another
I want to make a composite control that has a grid some labels boxes and an entry
so that I can reuse it in almost all of the entry data points in my app,  I have some triggers that handle validation  triggerText only allows text to be entered  triggerNumbers only allow numbers to be entered etc
I cannot figure out how to tell my composite control to use one trigger or the other
something like this <control:MySuperEntryControl LabelText="{Bindable mylabelText}" EntryText="{Bindable myEntryText}"  and  Something something use this particular trigger />
Any Ideas I can try?   It sounds like this would be something very common but I cannot find info on this
tried making a style that handles the trigger to somehow select a style or another, but did not get anywhere

you have to use stackoverflow tools to organize your question.

You can create a BindableProperty which allows string or enums. Which you can populate. For example, if you want a string trigger then property can be "string" or "number" for numbers or "password" for password text or their subsequent enums.
In your custom control you can trigger the binding using MultiBinding and DataTrigger and a Convertor which checks for matching for ex: StringEqualityConverter
For example for a button,

<Button Text="Save">
    <Button.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="{local:CustomEntry}">
       <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringEqualityConverter}">
            <Binding Path="YourProperty"/>
            <Binding Source="YourComparisonString"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
   </DataTrigger>
    <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="SomeValue"/>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers?view=net-maui-8.0#data-triggers
